# Maven - Include all tomcat dependencies in project

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

How can I include all tomcat default library jars in my project?

Is there a way to add the tomcat dependency below in pom.xml and these jars to be included?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.59</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This dependency doesn't work as I am getting:

```
$mvn clean install -U
...
Could not find artifact org.apache.tomcat:tomcat:jar:7.0.59 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
```

Moreover, the url http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/7.0.59/ exists, however no jar in there.

Comment: Maybe `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core` is close enough? It's intended for embedding Tomcat at runtime, though, so it probably contains classes that regular tomcat doesn't have.